# Reflection about line? Linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

So the question is asking to find the transformation in $R^2$ for a reflection around a standard y=mx+b line. I understand how to do the change of basis part. I don't understand the following part of the solution though.

[image]

Why was that transformation in standard basis chosen. I feel like I am missing something very obvious. Is it just because this is a flip over the x-axis? And if so why did they choose that?

Comment: If the line does not pass through the Origin, then (0,0) is no longer mapped onto (0,0) and thus this is no longer a linear transformation. The line of reflection must pass through the Origin. It seems like the author has used a change of basis with one vector on the line and the other vector perpendicular to it. The image vectors are then easily found and thus a matrix is then established.